# Are prime ideals mapped to prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two commutative rings and $\phi$ be homomorphism between them , if  $P$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then is $\phi(P)$  a  prime ideal of $B$?

I think the statement is false, but unfortunately I cannot come up with any suitable counterexample.

Please help.

Comment: The image of an ideal does not even have to be an ideal: try the inclusion mapping  $\mathbf Z \to \mathbf Q$ and look at the image of $n\mathbf Z$.  But if $\phi \colon A \to B$ is *surjective* then the image of an ideal is an ideal.

Comment: Thanks! I got it.

Comment: Try preimages. You may be shocked!